# Wildcards in Makefile rules

Tags: makefile, wildcard

I have the following rules in a Makefile

```
%.00.png: %.dat
    genimg.py $< $@

%.10.png: %.dat
    genimg.py $< $@

%.20.png: %.dat
    genimg.py $< $@

%.30.png: %.dat
    genimg.py $< $@
```

where `genimg.py` is a script that generates an image based on the data in a `*.dat` file and a parameter which is stored in the name of the target file (00, 10, 20, 30). Is it possible to combine all these rules into one? I tried the obvious:

```
%.*.png: %.dat
    genimg.py $< $@
```

but that does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way to combine this into one rule.

But, you could auto-generate the rules.  Assuming you can write it as a single line you can use something like:

```
SIZES := 00 10 20 30

$(foreach S,$(SIZES),$(eval %.$S.png: %.dat ; genimg.py $$< $$@))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something very close to this using [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html), the [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) `$*` and the [`basename`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#File-Name-Functions) function :

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.png: $$(basename $$*).dat
    genimg.py $< $@
```

But this has the following limitation that a file named `foo.png` will still be fitted by this rule and depend upon `foo.dat`.
If this is not acceptable behavior for your application, you can use the more elaborate version :

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
# This relies on the assumption that there's no file named '/-'
%.png: $$(if $$(word 2,$$(subst ., ,$$*)),$$(word 1,$$(subst ., ,$$*)).dat,/-)
    genimg.py $< $@
```

But this comes with the additional limitation that a file named `a.b.10.png` will get as a prerequisite `a.dat` instead of the expected `a.b.dat`.